# Make input field appear when clicking a button, in a *ngFor loop using *ngIf in Angular/TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to use *ngIf when it is used in a *ngFor loop.

HTML:

```
<div *ngFor="let movie of movieList" class="movieRow">
<button (click)="onEdit()">click</button>
<div *ngIf="isEditEnable">
  <input />
</div>
```

TypeScript:

```
    isEditEnable: boolean = false;
    onEdit() {
    this.isEditEnable = !this.isEditEnable;
    }
```

When this is run, the boolean changes globally, for all of the movies in movieList, and therefore the input box appears for them all.
I am trying to only make this appear for the clicked movie.

Should I use events, and if so, how should I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You're missing a closing `</div>` tag :)

Comment: Yeah, this was just a code snippet so it is lower in the code, but thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a single `isEditEnable` property for all the movies. Clicking on the button for any the movies would toggle it and show the input field for each movie.

Instead, you should add a similar property to each movie item. Your `*ngIf` will become this:

```
*ngIf="movie.isEditEnable"
```

Comment: This would work, but the problem is that I also use the movie object for posting, and if I would add a property that is not in the database, I think this would give me problems.

Comment: You could easily filter this property out by using the spread operator before posting:
`const { isEditEnable, ...movieToPost } = movie`